# How to edit unique field in mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

How to edit unique field value in mysql database? if I edit it in phpmyadmin i get what i need, but if i do this from .php by form my field doesn't edites( Whats wrong ?

here is sql code

```
$result = mysql_query ("UPDATE client SET Code='$Code', FirstName='$FirstName', LastName='$LastName', DateBirth='$DateBirth', Other='$Other' WHERE Code=$Code");
```

Comment: I don't understand: you're doing `"UPDATE client SET Code='$Code' ... WHERE Code=$Code"`... what do you expect from this?

Comment: i'm trying to update client information, but is same case i need to change code, maybe i get my answer, problem is in WHERE)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've already told you in my comment, your query is a nonsense, because you're trying to update unique field `Code` with the same value it's already inside!!
If you're trying to update customer infos, you should do:

```
UPDATE client SET 
    FirstName = '$FirstName', 
    LastName  = '$LastName', 
    DateBirth = '$DateBirth', 
    Other     = '$Other' 
WHERE Code = $Code
```

If you need to change code, you should assign it a different value

```
UPDATE client SET 
    Code      = $newCode,
    FirstName = '$FirstName', 
    LastName  = '$LastName', 
    DateBirth = '$DateBirth', 
    Other     = '$Other' 
WHERE Code = $Code
```

Note that if `Code` column is a string, you should use `'$Code'` everywhere...

Answer (score 0):

You should try this :

```
$result = mysql_query ("UPDATE client SET Code='$Code', FirstName='$FirstName', LastName='$LastName', DateBirth='$DateBirth', Other='$Other' WHERE Code='$Code'");
```

Comment: i.e. change `WHERE Code=$Code` to `WHERE Code='$Code'` in case $Code doesn't (always!) contain a "pure" number.

Comment: $result = mysql_query ("UPDATE client SET Code='$Code', FirstName='$FirstName', LastName='$LastName', DateBirth='$DateBirth', Other='$Other' WHERE Code=$CodeH");      it's good

Answer (score 0):

If you indend on changing the `Code` field, then maybe you should use another variable for the `WHERE` clause, because you're currently looking for the "to-be" value instead of the current one.

Answer (score 0):

your query is setting the Code to $Code where Code is $Code
So I would guess you need to change one of those $Code references to something else.

Do you have the old value for Code in that context? If not - you need to pass it there through the page request or the session.